# Domain Name Does Not Exist In The Database in DNN 5.6.2

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

i found this error "Domain Name Does Not Exist In The Database" in DNN 5.6.2.

when i run my web site in another computer that time this kind of error is genetared.

i dont know why this happen.

Answer (score 2):

I know this might be very late, but for anyone having this issue, 
I had the same issue, after I made sure that I have updated the "Portal Alias" table in db, to have a HTTP Alias (for my local host, I set it to localhost:8089 which was equal to what I had set up in IIS binding for DNN website), with the portal ID of 0 (as my portal id was 0),
I was checking to be sure I have updated web.config file with data base connection strings, but then I realized there were two points for database connection in web.config, and I was missing one of them.
So make sure to update both two connections as:

```
1) <connectionStrings>
2) <appSettings>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

How have you set up your website and how are you accessing your site from this other computer?

**I'm assuming you have done this**
1) Add binding to your IIS site, www.xxx.com or something
2) Set up the hostname on your domain so its accessible to all
3) Log in as Host and add a new portal alias to your portal

if it's http://localhost/xxx that you've set up the website on, and have not set up a non-localhost url for it, that will be the issue at hand.

To access it from another computer, you'll have to use the PortalAlias. Get access to your database and you'll be able to see all the portal aliases that your portal can use.